# how to access var inside the spring data mongodb using the JPA

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

i want to access the var that i have created of the mongodb inside the spring boot. Here i am using spring data mongodb to communicate with the database.

```
> var regno = {num : 1};
> regno;
{ "num" : 1 }
```

want to use this number and every time after using it i want to increase this number

-- Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hey, do I get it right that you create `var` in MongoDB shell's session and would like to retrieve it in Spring Entity? Did you try `$$<variable>` sign expression in query? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/

Comment: can you please help a bit more ?? related to spring i.e how to that in Spring .. i have understood how this works in shell.. (i am new in Spring )